# fscanf reads the last integer twice

Tags: c, file-io

I have the following simple program to read from a text file (num.txt). The text file has numbers 1 2 3 4 5 in each line. When I run the program, it prints 5 twice. Can anybody tell me why is this happening, and how to fix it? thanks in advance

```
int main(void)
{
   int number;
   FILE *file;

   int i = 0;;

   file = fopen("num.txt", "r");

   while (!feof(file)){

      fscanf(file, "%d", &number);
      printf("%d\n", number);
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Here's my text file num.xtx

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And here's the program output

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

There is an extra 5

Comment: `while (!feof(file)){` :: feof() is the cause of the problem

Comment: May I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)?

Comment: What is the value returned by fscanf when you see that last 5? I'm betting it isn't 1. ;-)

Comment: Not being judgmental, but curious: why did you consider using `while (!feof(file)){`? Teacher, fellow student, book, guess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the man page of `scanf` family of functions,

> The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before
>   either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
>   `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream is set, and `errno` is set to indicate the
>   error.

This means that the last successful `fscanf` call reads the last line from the stream `file` after which the `while` loop condition `!feof(file)` is true because the end of file condition is not met yet. This means the loop is executed one extra time and the previous value of the variable `number` is printed again.

Please read this - [`while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

You should check the return value of `scanf` instead of checking the end of file indicator on the file stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>   

int main(void) {
   int number;
   FILE *file = fopen("num.txt", "r");

   // check file for NULL in case there
   // is error in opening the file
   if(file == NULL) {
      printf("error in opening file\n");
      return 1;
   }      

   // check if fscanf call is successful 
   // by checking its return value for 1.
   // fscanf returns the number of input
   // items successfully matched and assigned
   while(fscanf(file, "%d", &number) == 1)
      printf("%d\n", number);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: while(fscanf(file, "%d", &number) == 1) may confuse users reading more then 1 record per scanf call (for example " fscanf(file, "%d %d", &number1,&munber2)" ). I  would use  : while(fscanf(file, "%d", &number) != EOF).

Answer (score 5):

The second time `fscanf` failed and didn't write anything to `number`, that's why it's still 5 from the last time. To know if `fscanf` succeeded, you have to check its return value.

`fscanf` returns the number of arguments that it wrote. In your case, if it returns 1, it worked; if it returns 0, it didn't. This is what you should check instead of `feof`.

```
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &number) == 1)
{
    printf("%d\n", number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with `feof` you need to add one more test inside the loop:

```c
while (!feof(file)) {
      fscanf(file, "%d", &number);

      // add a second test before printing
      if (!feof(file))
        printf("%d\n", number);
}
```